# chrome extension match url check for subpath

Tags: google-chrome-extension, match, glob

I want to run my `index.js` if the url is `https://www.themoviedb.org/movie/<any-movie-id>` but dont want it to run if it has subpath like `https://www.themoviedb.org/movie/<any-movie-id>/<sub-path>`

```json
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["https://*.themoviedb.org/movie/*", "https://*.themoviedb.org/tv/*"],
        "js": ["src/index.js"],
        "css": ["src/index.css"]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `exclude_globs` and do something like this

```json
"matches": [
  "https://www.themoviedb.org/movie/*"
],
"exclude_globs": ["https://www.themoviedb.org/movie/*/*"]
```